# OpenVPN Server Loses internet connection

Tags: vpn, openvpn

Server side:  A VM with ubuntu 16.04 on Apache Cloudstack. 
CLient: A physical ubuntu 14.04 machine.

I did a port forwarding for UDP connection in the cloud.

I installed server side from this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04). 
I can smoothly run server and client side and can ping each other. I wanted to tunnel all client side traffic through VPN, hence in /etc/openvpn/server.conf I uncommented 
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

But whenever the VPN is up on both sides I lose internet connection on the server side. This is not desired. What could cause this? I see no error. Just the VPn tunnel is the only way the server is contacting.

Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: This might help: https://serverfault.com/questions/648118/openvpn-not-default-gateway-for-all-traffic

Answer (score 0):

Try to Diagnosis the VPN and delete all cookies and temp files from your system, just restart and connect your VPN. Once connected check the log files.